# Instance failure when connection to DB through C# code

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, database

I am getting this error while connecting to database , though this error is not seen everytime.

The connection string in c# is as follows,

> "Data Source=" + machineName + "\\" + instance + ";Initial
>   Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True";

When i narrowed down the exact place the exception is thrown, it happens to be when database connection open is attempted.

> DBConnection.con.Open();

This issue is not reproducible consistenly.

I searched alot and was not able to figure out why this was happenend.I verified the suggestion that was shared,

- Verified that instance being used and SQL service is up and running.
- TCP/IP  is enabled and remote connections are allowed.
- Checked the SQL error logs and couldn't figure out anything wrong there.
- The connection string has proper format of machinename\instance .

I also restarted the SQL service mutliple times but no luck with that too. I am stuck and do not know how to proceed forward.
Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: Internet connection issue?

Comment: Whats the actual text you are getting as a result of your datasource concoction?

Comment: Are you trying to connet to local SQL? If not take into account that using Integrated Security = true, the Windows User must have access to SQL server. In others words I would try to use SQL Server authentication as another check, providing credentials on con string

Comment: What is the exception and its detail? Are you building the connection string that way because you are connecting to different servers dynamically? If so do the same ones fail? `SqlConnectionStringBuilder` is a better way to build connection strings if only to avoid mal-escaped characters like you have in "\".

Comment: The connection is through LAN. Not getting any result from datasource, just a "instance failure" exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting to your database from Visual Studio (SQL Server Explorer). Once successful, right-click on the server instance, copy the connection string. Like this, you are sure about the syntax. A database connection is meant to be on a local network. If you connect to a database over internet, implement a webservice.

Have fun :)

Comment: As this issue is not reproducible all the time i ruled out connection string related problem. Most of times it connects and works as expected. Also the connection to database is not over internet it's just a distributed setup with SQL in separate machine. I also confirmed there is no issue with port being used by other SQL instances too.

Comment: Also verified the connection string obtained from VS is same the one I am using.

Comment: Ok, it might be related to \\ which is an escape sequence in C#. Please try : either to declare your string as a literal : @"mystring wont be evaluated" or remove one of the \.